# Haskell List Comprehensions

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I'm attempting to do a haskell question as I'm trying to learn Haskell.

The question gives me the following type definitions:
`type Word = String`
`type Line = [Word]`
`type Book = [Line]`

The question then asks me to define a function index :: Word -> Book -> [Int] which takes a word and a book, and returns the line numbers the words appear on. eg:
`index "example" [["example", "town"], ["example", "cat", "this"]] = [1,2]`

So far I have used zip book [1 .. length book] to attach the line numbers to each line, so that would give me

`[(["example","town"],1),(["example","cat","this"],2)]`

How would I then extract only the line numbers? I am assuming I would use list comprehensions but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The general list comprehensions scheme for these things is

```
g xs = [i | (x,i) <- zip xs [1..], pred x]
```

`pred` is a predicate acting on elements of `xs`, the input list; only for those that pass the test, their original indices are included in the output. Of course this can be done with higher order functions, as

```
g xs = map snd . filter (pred . fst) . (`zip` [1..]) $ xs
```

`(.)` is the function composition operator: `pred . fst == (\p -> pred (fst p))`. Thus the above line could also be written

```
g xs = map snd . filter (\(x,i) -> pred x) . (`zip` [1..]) $ xs
```

whatever is more readable to you.

*update:* `filter` is also implementable as

```
filter pred = concatMap (\x -> [x | pred x])
```

so the mapping can be fused in, giving us

```
g :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Int]
g pred = concatMap (\(x,i) -> [i | pred x]) . (`zip` [1..])
```

`concatMap` can also be replaced with `foldMap`, `join . map ...` and even `asum . map ...`.

Comment: another question (I didn't want to open a new one, and PM is not existent in SO):

Comment: Is the list comprehension more efficient or the higher order function implementation?

Comment: @kaan: They both compile to same code if you turn on optimizations, so pick whatever suits you more.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map`, which applies a function to every element in a list. The function you want to apply is `snd`, which extracts the second element.

```
λ> let xs = [(["example","town"],1),(["example","cat","this"],2)]
λ> map snd xs
[1,2]
```

You might want to show us the rest of your code. You mentioned that you used `Tzip book [1 .. length book]` -- there are usually easier and more efficient ways than using the `length` function. We might be able to suggest a more "Haskellish" way of doing it.

**Edit**: filtering

We can filter the list by writing a simple function to find all of the entries that contain the word we're interested in. In the example below, I've defined `containsWord` for this purpose:

```
λ> let xs = [(["example","town"],1),(["example","cat","this"],2)]
λ> let containsWord w (ws,_) = w `elem` ws
λ> let ys = filter (containsWord "cat") xs
λ> map snd ys
[2]
```

Or, if you want to define the function inline:

```
λ> let xs = [(["example","town"],1),(["example","cat","this"],2)]
λ> let ys = filter (\(zs,_) -> "cat" `elem` zs) xs
λ> map snd ys
[2]
```

You can of course use list comprehensions for all this stuff. But you may find that using functions like `map` and `filter` result in more readable code. If you look back at your code a few months from now, you'll immediately understand the purpose of `map` and `filter`, but it takes closer inspection to figure out what a list comprehension is actually *doing*. I prefer to use list comprehensions only for situations that aren't already covered by familiar functions.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I filter the list? I can easily filter the list before applying the zip function, but it doesn't let me filter after applying it because an integer appears at the end of each element on the list. However, if I filter before zipping, that means the line numbers would be incorrect.. For example, if I filtered for "cat" and then zipped, it would give me 1 for the line number

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in others posts you can use the `zip` function to decorate each line with a line number. You can then use a list comprehension to search through:

```
search :: Word -> Book -> [Int]  
search w b =  
  [n | (line, n) <- lines, elem w line]  
  where lines = zip b [1..]
```

You can also define the the function using `foldl` (not sure it's good style though, I am still a beginner in Haskell):

```
search :: Word -> Book -> [Int]
search w b =
  fst $ foldl foo ([], 1) b
  where foo (rs, n) line | elem w line = (n : rs, n+1)
                         | otherwise = (rs, n+1)
```

You could also define this recursively, etc. Hope it helped!

Comment: a. you're recreating an existing function, `filter`; b. you do this with left fold, thus introducing unnecessary strictness, e.g. it won't work on infinite lists as `foldl` *always* consumes the whole of input list; c. the result list gets built in reversed order; d. but you've got the idea of passing along the state as we traverse the list, see if you can make it work with `unfoldr` or `iterate`. :)

Comment: also, `foldr (\line next i -> if (elem w line) then i:next (i+1) else next (i+1)) (const []) book 1`. :)